# Install bundle 'missing' files to open program

Tags: windows, help

I downloaded both the browser installer, and the 'expert' packages. After getting error with the 'wizard', I tried the other; neither works.

I see the Tor Browser (wizard) has a note it is an unstable d\l. I can see why.

As far as the other installer, I get a 'command' box full of info, but it stops there. Nothing happens after that.

Where am I going wrong?  What do I do to correct these issues?  Someone help!!